# Dart/Flutter break in for loop

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart

I am unable to break the for loop.

```
  for (int j = 0; j < questions[_questionId].getanswers.length; j++) {
    if (questions[_questionId].getanswers[j].id == _selectedValue &&
        questions[_questionId].getanswers[j].correct == true) { //Condition A
      if (score == 0) {
        score = questions[_questionId].questionmarks;
        break;
      } else {
        score = score + questions[_questionId].questionmarks;
        break;
      }
      break;
    } else {
      if (incorrectlist == ' ') {
        incorrectlist = questions[_questionId].id.toString();
      } else {
        if (!incorrectlist.contains(questions[_questionId].id.toString())) {
          incorrectlist =
              incorrectlist + ',' + questions[_questionId].id.toString();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to either update my score when the condition meets or append the string incorrectlist.
This code works when the Condition A Fails, i.e it does not update the score. However, when the
Condition A passes, it updates the score and also appends the incorrectlist. Why is this not breaking after the Condition A satisfies ?

Comment: What evidence do you have that the you are not breaking out of the loop when your conditions are met?  Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: there is no way when "Condition A" is met your loop is not break

Answer (score 0):

Are you breaking where you should be returning?

Comment: This should really be a comment and not an answer.